# Select HTML5 video closed-caption language in Selz Plyr

Tags: html, video, plyr.js

I've been testing Plyr videos in our web app. Closed caption toggle works, but does Plyr also feature selecting from multiple languages? For example:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="source.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track kind="captions" label="English captions" src="sample.vtt" 
srclang="en"></track>
  <track kind="captions" label="French captions" src="sample-fr.vtt" 
srclang="fr" ></track>
  <track kind="captions" label="Italian captions" src="sample-it.vtt" srclang="it" ></track>

</video>
```

I would expect to get a select-list of language options, but doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

srclang attribute indicates what language each subtitle files' contents are in. Can you please provide an example?

[Building caption Menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video#Building_a_caption_menu)